# Half of vram is usable?

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I have a video card (Nvidia GTX 980M) with 4GB of Vram. But one line in the output of the command `sudo dmesg | grep drm` is :

`[    1.927238] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M`

Is it an issue ? How can I make my system using all of the 4GB ?

EDIT : Okay it's weird, my 4GB are actually in use when I run many benchmarks at the same time (according to nvidia-settings)

Comment: How have you come to the conclusion it has 4GB vRAM?

Comment: It's the laptop specifications. Plus, nvidia-settings report 4039 MB as 'Total dedicated memory' but it seems that the graphic card never use more than 2GB, atleast using wine.